# Use registers without preserving them? (assembly)

Tags: windows, assembly, x86-64, cpu-registers, win64

After the Windows calling convetion, only RAX,RCX,RDX,r8 and r9 can be used without having to preserve them (called volatile) and the rest are called nonvolatile (must be preserved).

Is there something wrong to using nonvolatiles registers without preserving them? (I often do and I haven't met any problem so far)

The calling convention says that only RCX,RDX,r8 and r9 are used for passing integer parameters and extra ones should be passed on stack.

Is there any downsides to using r10 as a fifth parameter instead of the stack? (knowing that memory is at least 100 times slower than registers, I try to make the best use of registers)

Why would the calling convention stop at 4 registers for passing arguments when there is a whole dozen extra registers?

Comment: Most functions probably have 4 or fewer parameters on average (just a guess). If you used all available registers for parameters (and your function had a lot of parameters) then you would have to save the contents of registers (on the stack for example) before you could use them in your function. Likely the 64-bit ABI developers were looking for balance. Some registers were used to speed up access to function parameters, but leave registers available without the overhead of having to save them.

Comment: If you use nonvolatile registers without preserving them then you are just lucky your program *seems* to work. This is very bad practice and can lead to weird and wonderful behaviour later on. If a register is marked as non-volatile, please for the love of an unproven omnipotent entity or the next developer that may have to maintain your code - Preserve nonvolatile registers!

Comment: @MichaelPetch Is it good enough to push all non-volatile registers once when entering the main procedure and restoring them at end of program or should they be pushed and popped of stack every single time they are about to be overwritten?

Comment: Probably should point out that if you have arguments to your function that are floats then they will be passed in XMM0-XMM3

Comment: @Henri: their state only matters when you return.  push/pop the ones you use at the start/end of your function.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info: One of the "learning resources" links is to a question about why some registers are call-preserved and some not.  "volatile" has a different technical meaning in C, so I wouldn't suggest using it that way in this context.  The Linux 64bit calling convention has more scratch (call-clobbered) registers, which I think is likely to lead to better code overall.  I'm not sure if there's much agreement on that.

Comment: You can push all non-volatile registers at the beginning of your function and restore them at the end, but that is a lot of overhead if you are just using a few nonvolatile registers. I'd only save/restore the non-volatile registers you will clobber. You can save/restore them at the beginning or end of your function.

Comment: If you are using a non-volatile register in your function and you need it preserved across a function call that you would have to make then you may have to save/restore it around the function call. This isn't a problem if your function doesn't call other functions. If you do call other functions, it is the caller's (your function) responsibility to preserve any registers it may need to be saved across a _CALL_

Comment: Whatever you do, make sure you generate the proper unwind codes so that the operating system will do the right thing if an exception occurs.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: In your last comment, I think you mean "if you are using a *volatile* register".  If you keep everything that needs to survive a `call` to a child function in call-preserved registers, you don't need to save/restore anything around the `call`; just restore the call-preserved registers before returning yourself.

Comment: @Peter, Yes, was a fingers faster than the brain error. was meant to be volatile. I have corrected the comment.

Comment: If you are using a volatile register in your function and you need it preserved across a function call that you would have to make then you may have to save/restore it around the function call. This isn't a problem if your function doesn't call other functions. If you do call other functions, it is the caller's (your function) responsibility to preserve any registers it may need to be saved across a CALL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing this out loud as an answer as I believe that @Michael Petch (and others) point need to be stressed out, *for future reference*, with more than a comment.

Violating the [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) is it not bad practice, **it is just plain wrong**.
As wrong as the kind of things like deferencing a dangling pointer, writing to const memory  and so on.

---

The reasoning behind is quite obvious: caller will usually have temporary data in a non volatile register, it can be an index into a string, a sum, a cryptographic hash or whatever.

---

If you control the ABI, you make the rules; if you don't, you don't.

Answer (score 0):

You "need" to preserve the non-volatile registers so the caller of your function can rely on it to leave the values in these registers unchanged.

Also, just think, if you write a function that uses these registers as parameters instead of the stack, where would the caller have to store his values?
The stack, there's no way around it at some point.

You can indeed push non-volatile registers to the stack and pop them back later would you need to.